# javascript RegEX with round brackets in pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

The below script is returning null. It is returning correctly if I remove round brackets in str and patt1 for the text spot_Northeast(300)_comment

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var str="0000CentralGasEform2,0000CentralGasEformNew,spot_Northeast(300)_comment"; 
var patt1=/\bspot_Northeast(300)_comment/g;
document.write(str.match(patt1));
</script>
```

---

In my application, the value in str is taken from the cookies and the value in patt1 is dynamic based on the window opened

```
regExp = new RegExp('\\b'+FormOpen+'\\b', 'g');
```

Here FormOpen is dynamic. Then I replace the match in cookie

```
var temp=CookieList.replace(regExp,"");
```

Is there a way to tell RegEX that () is normal text instead of hardcoding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

escape them

`var patt1=/\bspot_Northeast\(300\)_comment/g;`

() are reserved characters in the context (.*) for instance, you need to tell the regex engine to treat them as normal text through a process called escaping

Comment: Thanks. In my application, the value in str is taken from the cookies and the value in patt1 is dynamic based on the window opened                 regExp = new RegExp('\\b'+FormOpen+'\\b', 'g');

Here FormOpen is dynamic. Then I replace the match in cookie

var temp=CookieList.replace(regExp,"");

Is there a way to tell RegEX that () is normal text instead of hardcoding?

Comment: Cookies aren't trusted so their values shouldn't be used in anything that is evaluated. I realize that is probably of little concern in this example but i guess its worth noting. Maybe its not relevant, since they would only be affecting them selves i guess its just not an approach *i* would take?

Answer (score 0):

Escape the brackets:

```
var patt1=/\bspot_Northeast\(300\)_comment/g;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the round braces with '\' escape character as they have special meaning in reg ex
your reg ex would look something like..

```
var patt1=/\bspot_Northeast\(300\)_comment/
```